# Any idea why the font of the title in Chrome changes?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, fonts, title

Just curious, I don't know much about how fonts/kerning works, but does anyone have any idea why this happens?

As you can see in this screenshot of the current version of Chrome on Windows 7, the "Asdf." before the envelope icon appears in a distinctly different font than the "Asdf" that is inserted after.!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljOtJ.png)

Comment: I think the *font* (typeface) is the same. It's the *size* that is changing. No idea why without knowing more details. Is this a result of HTML/CSS code you've written? If so, please post it.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that it appears different on this website, and it appears to be due to the symbol. Notice how the size resets after the period (.com appears normal). https://www.guerrillamail.com/

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, it is in the title of the tab (in the Chrome app itself). My guess is there is some kind of font substitution happening in Chrome to show [the envelope character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2709/index.htm) and during that process, the size gets set wrong (or doesn't get reset correctly). Maybe consider filing a bug with Chrome, though this doesn't seem like a major problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The envelope symbol on the tab is shown by Windows with a fallback font, because Segoe UI (the main Windows font) does not have it. Thus, the text after it is shown with the fallback font as well, which IMHO is a bug.